# Create a button for a list

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

How to separate the (Add Load) Button from the list? I want to place the button somewhere else and the list to appear at the bottom or centre, as per my need. When I remove the "Add Load" button from the list , the list doesn't show up. And is there any way, I can create a fixed size for a list so that it doesn't take up the whole screen and only appears in a certain size of the screen.

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainView: View {
    @State var br = Double()
    @State var loadpay = Double()
    @State var gp: Double = 0
    @State var count: Int = 1
    @State var listcheck = Bool()
    @StateObject var taskStore = TaskStore()
    func addNewToDo() {
        taskStore.tasks.append(Task(id: String(taskStore.tasks.count + 1), toDoItem: "load \(count)", amount: Double(gp)))
    }

    func stepcount() {
        count += 1
    }

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            HStack(spacing: 15) { Button(String(format: "Add Load"), action: { print("Load is ")

                gp += loadpay

            })
            Button(action: { addNewToDo(); stepcount() }, label: {
                Text("")
            })
            }

            ForEach(self.taskStore.tasks) {
                task in
                Text(task.toDoItem)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Task: Identifiable {
    var id = String()
    var toDoItem = String()
    var amount: Double = 0
}

class TaskStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var tasks = [Task]()
}
```

Comment: With your current code, the "list" doesn't show up when the "Add Load" button is removed because the `tasks` array is empty and there isn't any way to add items to it. In terms of separating them, how about using `Section { }` to wrap the different sections (ie the `Button` and the `ForEach`)?

Comment: I have tried that too, however, when you put them into different sections, The Add Load button will take up a lot of space as it will be under a list. If I remove the Add Load button from the list, the list won't appear. I want the AddLoad button to look like a simple button and not take up space. For example you see how save, or next or Edit button looks like. They don't look like a list.

Comment: It sounds like you want something in the `Toolbar` -- I'd search for "SwiftUI toolbar" and see if that leads you to what you're looking for.

Comment: I don't want it in the navigation bar I just want it to appear anywhere on the screen wherever I need without having to be it in a list. So when I click the add load button, the list appears on the screen. But I am not able to separate the Add Load Button from the list.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. You said to look at "Save", "Next" or "Edit" buttons, which generally appear in a toolbar (they don't appear anywhere in your code). You also say that you want "AddLoad" button to "not take up space", which doesn't make sense -- unless it's invisible, it's going to take up space. Then, you want it to "appear anywhere on the screen wherever I need". Can you draw a picture of what you are looking for so that it's clear what the goal is?

Comment: In short I mean, I don't want the Add button to appear in a list. I just want the list separate and the button separate. But when I separate the button from the list , the list doesn't appear. List{ } should not contain Add Load Button.

Comment: You don't have `List` anywhere in your code.

Comment: I have used Form instead of List. So I don't the Add Load Button to appear in a Form or a List. Thanks

Comment: Wrap everything in a `VStack` and move the `Button`s outside of the `Form`

Comment: Tried that as well, doesn't work. If I move the button outside the list/Form, the list doesn't appear. I hope if you can try running the code which will give you a better understanding what I mean. Thanks

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean, because your description of what you want is quite unclear to me still, but I've given a shot at an answer (with what I described in my previous comment). If it doesn't work for you, I'll delete it.

Comment: Thanks mate, I just did a silly mistake. All good. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your `Form` in a `VStack` and have the `Button`s be sibling elements to the `Form`:

```
struct MainView: View {
    @State var br = Double()
    @State var loadpay = Double()
    @State var gp: Double = 0
    @State var count: Int = 1
    @State var listcheck = Bool()
    @StateObject var taskStore = TaskStore()
    
    func addNewToDo() {
        taskStore.tasks.append(Task(id: String(taskStore.tasks.count + 1), toDoItem: "load \(count)", amount: Double(gp)))
    }

    func stepcount() {
        count += 1
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: { gp += loadpay }) {
                Text("Add Load")
            }
            Button(action: {
                addNewToDo()
            }) {
                Text("Add to do")
            }
            Form {
                ForEach(self.taskStore.tasks) {
                    task in
                    Text(task.toDoItem)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```